# How Data as a service (DaaS) differs from Storage as a service(StaaS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, distributed-computing

Can any one please explain how DaaS differs from StaaS. Is there any reliable service provider for DaaS like Amazon S3 for StaaS?

Comment: Data as a Service? I haven't heard of this before. I'd start with asking myself, what problem are you trying to solve? – I wouldn't chase concepts or terms or providers before understanding what I am trying to do.

Comment: Data as a Service exist, heard about Oracle Data Cloud recently.don't know more about that.Iam not trying to solve any problem. Just researching and checking out different cloud providers.